# Testing a final class in JUnit

Tags: junit

All,

I have a class file that is used to store all the constants that would be used throughout my application. The class file contains only constants and methods JUnit test case for such a class? If yes, how should I test such a class file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't sound like a great idea to keep all the constants for the whole application in a single class to start with. Why separate them from the class which is most closely related to the value? For example, if you have a default timeout for authentication requests, keep it with your authentication service (or whatever).

If you *really* want to have a class with just constants, I don't think it needs any tests. Tests should exercise logic - constants don't have any logic.